# Persist user Auth Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Auth with google sign in Flutter. I am able to sign in however when I close the app(kill it), I have to sign up all over again. So is there a way to persist user authentication till specifically logged out by the user? 
Here is my auth class

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class Auth {
  FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;
  FirebaseUser _user;

  Auth() {
    this._firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  }

  Future<bool> isLoggedIn() async {
    this._user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    if (this._user == null) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  Future<bool> authenticateWithGoogle() async {
    final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
    await googleUser.authentication;
    this._user = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithGoogle(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    if (this._user == null) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
    // do something with signed-in user
  }
}
```

Here is my start page where the auth check is called.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'auth.dart';
import 'login_screen.dart';
import 'chat_screen.dart';

class Splash extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _Splash createState() => _Splash();
}

class _Splash extends State<Splash> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          value: null,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _handleStartScreen();
  }

  Future<void> _handleStartScreen() async {
    Auth _auth = Auth();
    if (await _auth.isLoggedIn()) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/chat");
    }
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginScreen(auth: _auth,)));
  }
}
```

Comment:  can you add the code you're using for login? normally you wouldn't need to persist anything to achieve that - it just works. add the code where you detect the user have already logged in. its probably a probeem in your routing logic.

Comment: I'm running isLoggedIn() at the start of the app to decide whether to start from login screen or main screen.

Comment: @Feu Posted the code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe your problem is routing. In my apps I use `FirebaseAuth` and it works just as you say you wanted to, and I don't persist any login token. However, I don't know why your approach of using a getUser is not working.

Try to adjust your code to use `onAuthStateChanged`. EDIT: As of 2022, with Flutter 3, I noticed it worked better with `userChanges`  instead.

Basically, on your `MaterialApp`, create a `StreamBuilder` listening to `_auth.userChanges()` and choose your page depending on the Auth status.

I'll copy and paste parts of my app so you can have an idea (see below).

```dart
[...]

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Future<void> main() async {
  FirebaseApp.configure(
    name: '...',
    options:
      Platform.isIOS
        ? const FirebaseOptions(...)
        : const FirebaseOptions(...),
    );
  
  [...]  

  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: '...',
    home: await getLandingPage(),
    theme: ThemeData(...),
  ));
}

Future<Widget> getLandingPage() async {
  return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
    stream: _auth.userChanges(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData && (!snapshot.data!.isAnonymous)) {
        return HomePage();
      }
      
      return AccountLoginPage();
    },
  );
}
```

**UPDATE**: As of 2024, I believe the recommended approach would be using [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router). In that sense, that code would change to something like:

```dart
[...]

  final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
    refreshListenable: GoRouterRefreshStream(FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges()),

  runApp(MaterialApp.router(
    [...]
    routeInformationProvider: _router.routeInformationProvider,
    routeInformationParser: _router.routeInformationParser,
    routerDelegate: _router.routerDelegate,
  ));

[...]
```

However (sorry!), it seems GoRouterRefreshStream was removed from go_router, and then I don't know YET what's the new way of doing it.

Comment: I added the main page where I am checking for already logged in user to route to the correct page.

Comment: Don't do the check as you're doing right now, use OnAuthStateChanged!

Comment: Ok. I'll do that. Also, can you tell me what is going wrong with this approach? I would like to know that.

Comment: Maybe the information about the logged user is not available at the moment you request it - but that's just a theory.  When listening to the onAuthStateChange, maybe that information becomes available slightly later and then you're able to catch it. Or maybe that's just a bug!  As a good side effect of this change, when you call the _auth logoff method, this stream will trigger that change as well, changing the page to login automatically!

Comment: great! as it's working, can you please accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, it was my mistake. Forgot to put the push login screen in else.

```
  Future<void> _handleStartScreen() async {
    Auth _auth = Auth();
    if (await _auth.isLoggedIn()) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/chat");
    }
    else {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginScreen(auth: _auth,)));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yeh, at least now I we know it's not a firebase bug.

Answer (score 2):

```
void main() {
FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User user) {
  if (user == null) {
          runApp(MyApp(auth : false);
        } else {
          runApp(MyApp(auth : false);
       }
    });
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool auth;
  MyApp({this.auth});
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  return MaterialApp(
  ......
  ......
  home: widget.auth ? MainScreen() : AuthScreen();
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shared_preferences` to keep alive your session even when you kill the app.
Here is the documentation https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences.

Also I've heard that it's possible to use sqlite to persist the session.

Comment: But what to store in sqllite. Also I am trying to make a chat app so it is kinda requred to be kept authorized so as to get new notifications.

Comment: Usually you store user's info but I think token is the most important thing to store.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.

Comment: i hope you make it!. Good luck!.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code. It should work fine.

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

auth.setPersistence(Persistence.SESSION);
```

Comment: Unhandled Exception: UnimplementedError: setPersistence() is only supported on web based platforms

Comment: @nadeesh try this: if(kIsWeb) auth.setPersistence(Persistence.SESSION);

Comment: Please check the documentation, it's only for web based platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my code, You can use userChanges() instead of authStateChanges()

Notifies about changes to any user updates.

This is a superset of both [authStateChanges] and [idTokenChanges]. It provides events on all user changes, such as when credentials are linked, unlinked and when updates to the user profile are made. The purpose of this Stream is for listening to realtime updates to the user state (signed-in, signed-out, different user & token refresh) without manually having to call [reload] and then rehydrating changes to your application.

```
final Stream<User?> firebaseUserChanges = firebaseAuth.userChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

One more simple example:

```
Future<bool> isUserLoggedIn() async {
   final User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
   return user != null;
}


class InitialScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: isUserLoggedIn(),
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data ?? false) {
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UnauthScreen()));
            } else {
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
            }
          }
         return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
       },
      ),
    );
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it by checking the firebase instance currentUser value. if null I routed to my Signup page. If not, then I routed to my HomePage. Not sure if there is anything wrong with this implementation (its working well so far) but seems simpler than the StreamBuilder solution posted above.

```
  home: getLandingPage(),
        routes: {
          (...)
 }

    Widget getLandingPage() {
  if (_auth.currentUser == null) {
    return SignupPage();
  } else {
    return HomePage();
  }
}
```